# print ASCII char on the console in C#

Tags: c#, console, ascii

I need to make the console to print ASCII char with 22 chars per "page". With an input, say "key", they will print the next 22 ASCII chars, and so on. The problem is with the "page turning" issue.

Here is my code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int i = 0;

        while (i <= 22)
        {
            Console.Write(i + " = " + (char)i);

            if (i < 22)
            {
                Console.Write((char)10);
            }

            i++;
        }

        Console.Write("Please press any key to turn page");

        Console.ReadKey();

        while (i > 22 && i <= 44)
        {
            Console.Write(i + " = " + (char)i);

            if (i < 44)
            {
                Console.Write((char)10);
            }

            i++;
        }

        Console.Write("Please press any key to turn page");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

I am essentially a newbie. I learn most things by myself, so if I am academically unbearable, please bear me, and just show me how it is done. I can get by from there. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is "page turning" issue you're facing? What is expected behaviour and what goes wrong?

Comment: And what do you expect `(char) i` to mean for all those control characters below 32? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Check your lecture notes - there is likely code control statement you are expected to use. Reasonably looking code which may be added as an answer will unlikely get you passing mark.

Comment: You can [clear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.console.clear.aspx) the console, but that's not really "page turning".

Comment: If you are trying to print to the console, you have to have a few things lined up. The console has to be using the character set/encoding that the program is. It also has to have font selected that contains the characters that want to print. That said, you might like to print the [C0 Controls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Latin_(Unicode_block)) as [Control Pictures](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2400.pdf). Do this by adding 0x2400 to `char` for the range 0 to 31. Output (appearance in browser will vary): ␀␁␂␃␄␅␆␇␈␉␊␋␌␍␎␏␐␑␒␓␔␕␖␗␘␙␚␛␜␝␞␟

Comment: What I mean by "page turning" is that I want the console to print the first 22 ASCII characters then when I press any key these first 22 ASCII characters will disappear and the next 22 ASCII characters will replace them.

Comment: Thank you Andy Korneyev. I learn the new method "console.clear", which is the essential answer to my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can understand, you're trying to print all ASCII table by portions of 22 characters.

This basically can be done by this code snippet:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 256; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i + " = " + (char)i);

    if (i % 22 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please press any key to turn page");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.Clear();
    }
}
```

Here we're iterating over all 255 characters in ASCII table, writing them line-by-line.

After each character printed out we're checking if it's 22'th characher counted (`i % 22` means "remainder from i divided to 22" - thus it will be 0 on 22, 44, 66 and so on).

In the case when it is 22, 44, 66 and so on character - we're printing our "press any key", reading the input and then clearing the screen.

That's it.

Comment: ASCII is 7 bit (0 to 127).

Comment: @Corak Historically it was. But a lot of years it is 8 bit, and technically 7-bits version is called US-ASCII.

Comment: @Andy: ASCII has never been 8 bit. Lots (though not all) of 8-bit codepages shared the first 128 characters with ASCII which was sometimes called "extended ASCII" by people who didn't know better. `US-ASCII` is simply the IANA and MIME name for the encoding.

Answer (score 5):

If you are not use `System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);` console will give different symbols or incorrect type face for some ASCII chars. More info about [GetEncoding(28591)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/encoding.cs,3b6090c501893c25)

> `/*internal const int ISO_8859_1  = 28591;// Latin1;*/`

```
using System;

namespace AsciiChart
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
                Console.Write(i+"=> ["+(char)i +"]  \n");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**Edited:**
For better format I edited the source with this.

```
 Console.Write(" "+(char)i );
   if (i % 16 == 0) { // 16*16 = 256
     Console.Write("\n");
 }
```